# Command line install valgrind and gdb on Majaro

Tags: gdb, valgrind, archlinux

Does anyone could provide me the command line for install valgrind and gdb on manjaro(archlinux) ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can install both packages at once with:

```
sudo pacman -S gdb valgrind
```